# Calling a django management command from a separate program

Tags: python, django

I have a custom django management command in one django project and I would like to call it from another django project.  Both are using virtualenv.  I also need to check the output of the command.

The command I want to call looks something like this:

`/home/path/to/bin/python /home/path/to/manage.py my-command --input-csv=/tmp/w2qGM1 --input-type=csv`

Where `/tmp/w2qGM1` is a temp csv file I've already created.

I've tried

`subprocess.call`

```
subprocess.call(CMD, shell=True,  env={
                'PYTHONPATH': os.pathsep.join(sys.path)})
```

---

`subprocess.check_output`

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    shlex.split(CMD),
    shell=True,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    env={'PYTHONPATH': os.pathsep.join(sys.path)}
)
```

---

`subprocess.Popen`

```
args = shlex.split(CMD)
output = subprocess.Popen(args).wait()
```

returns

```
Unknown command: 'my-command'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I've tried adding `cd /path/to/project/with/management/command/  && source bin/activate` to pickup that projects django settings.

I should also mention I have all the correct paths in my `PYTHONPATH` and the command works when run from the command line and programmatically.

Both projects have to use djagno 1.7.

Comment: Just copy over the command or the app containing the command.

Comment: That would be a lot of code and database duplication.

Comment: what you are saying makes no sense.

Comment: @hop thanks for the nice reply :D.  What do you mean it doesn't make sense?  If I copy an app I'm duplicating code.  In this instance I actually can't because my management command has a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: django projects are meant to be separated from each other and venvs even more so - if you're trying to go against the grain with that, you're on your own.
apps are meant to be loosely coupled (so "bunch of dependencies" sounds really scary) and installing one app in two different projects is not "duplicating" code. also, django supports more than one db per project, so "database duplication" doesn't sound applicable either.
I just think you're doing it wrong and one SO question is not enough space by far to set you right.

Comment: hop may be right, you might be asking for a lot of trouble by trying this. Could you use some other means of communication such as redis? Nevertheless, here are some ideas. 1) You say `/home/path/to/bin/python` - are you using the `bin/python` under the correct virtualenv? 2) What if you follow the suggestion and run `manage.py help` via subprocess and so on? That might give some insight into the project as the other project sees it. 3) What if you make a bash script with one argument that calls the management command and call that from python? Then you echo env vars and such in the script.